# App, or method for alerting me to low cadence, speed, or power on turbo trainer

Tags: turbo-trainer

I have a (none smart) turbo trainer, a ANT+ speed sensor and an ANT+ candence sensor.

When using the turbo trainer I have a habit of zoning out and letting my output drop. I'd really like some sort of alarm that goes off in the circumstances (either once, or until I get back over the threashold). My google fu is failing me.

I'm looking for answers like:

- This app has that feature (I am an apple user, but also have a fairly old android tablet)
- Use a bike generator and some tech for setting an alarm based on current.

Happy to do a fair amount of DIY to get this working.

EDIT: I'm already a user of Strava, so it would be fantastic if there was an (unmissable) alarm built into that.

Comment: My Garmin Edge 500 (old!) does this when I use a programmed Workout, i.e. I have to tell it what alarms to trigger. What app do you use already? I would be surprised if you _can't_ do this on any app

Comment: @Swifty I will edit the answer to include some apps I already use.

Comment: @Swifty - thank you - so far my best plan is seek out an Edge 500 on ebay :)

Comment: tbh interfacing with the 500 is a bit clunky, and if an app can do it, a used 500 might not even be the budget option. Point was really that if a 10 year old device has this feature, any modern option should too

Comment: Strava have a list of apps that work for indoor training and interface with Strava: https://www.strava.com/apps/indoor

Comment: Be aware that Apple devices don't interact with ANT+ sensors, you'd need Bluetooth devices.

Comment: 520 and 520+ are both capable of this